# Where can I find a cold-shoe adapter for Sony's multi-interface shoe?

Tags: light, studio-lighting, accessories

I need a small cold shoe adapter, with lower side 1/4" thread (screw or nut) and upper side multi interface shoe mechanical compatible.
I need this cold shoe for a off camera (rf wireless) Nissin a700+air1 flash compatible with Sony multi interface shoe (no electrical needs but must be mechanical compatible). The standard multi interface Sony stand flash is too big and impractical to my application. Where can I find an alternative?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What adapter can I use to mount my flash on a tripod?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40903/what-adapter-can-i-use-to-mount-my-flash-on-a-tripod)

Comment: I need this cold shoe for a off camera (rf wireless) Nissin a700+air1 flash compatible with Sony multi interface shoe. The base adapter must be compatible to this specific shoe (no electrical needs but must be  mechanical compatible).

Comment: It is possible that I am mistaken but I've seen several reports that warn that the standard shoe can break the fragile plastic base of the flash and also is slightly different from the traditional geometry. Also there is lack of the two holes for the safety plastic pins that exist in the multi interface shoe, that conserve the flash save, secure and in position. Sometimes the flash will be used in horizontal position.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to hold the flash in place while using it with the Air 1 Commander to control it remotely, *any* regular ISO-compatible cold shoe (i.e., a cold shoe that works for Canon, Nikon, Pentax, and everybody else) should fit.  The ISO standard specifies the physical dimensions of the shoe.